# Cannot get AsyncTask to recognize onPostExecute (all parameters/return values are correct) in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My class extending AsyncTask does not recognize and call onPostExecute after doInBackground completes. My code is below:

```
public class GetRankingsTASK extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Double> {

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params){
        //code to do stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(double avgrank) {
        //code to do more stuff
    }
}
```

onPostExecute creates a compiler error because the method does not override the superclass. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, Android Studio also gives me a warning saying onPostExecute is never used, but isn't it supposed to be called implicitly? any help is appreciated

Comment: are you returning something in **doInBackground**. Also are you calling your async task as **new GetRankingsTASK().execute()**

Answer (score 4):

Maybe because doInBackground is returning a Double (uppercase "D") -the object, and onPostExecute is expecting a double (lowercase "d") - the primitive type.  I'm not 100% sure, but this maybe why.  I would also need to see signature of your AsyncTask class to be sure.

**Edited this comment so future readers would hopefully understand easier.

Comment: It can be true, because `Double` is object, while `double` is primitive-type.

Comment: That was it. Can't believe I didn't notice that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is also to add types, when you want to extend `AsyncTask` next time `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`. Then Android Studio will generate methods for you.

Example:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer,Float,Double> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Double aDouble) {
        super.onPostExecute(aDouble);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        return null;
    }
}
```